# loading javascript asynchronously from /WEB-INF/ using a servlet: general concern

Tags: javascript, servlets, asynchronous, production

I am loading javascript files asynchronously in my Java EE web application using a servlet.

The **js** files are placed under **/WEB-INF/js/** folder.

The process flow goes as following:

in **index.jsp**:

```
<script src="/servlet/mainLoader.js">
```

the **servlet** does the neccessary job to get the **js** file from inside **/WEB-INF/js/** .

So basically i call **one main js** file **mainLoader.js** which itself loads the rest of the js files in my application.
The reason behind this architecture, is to hide some critical info in the **js** files, so users won't be able to surf the file's path and check the source code.

I have two questions:
- Is this considered a bad practice?
- Currently i am developing my app **locally (localhost)** , will this **js** loading system cause problems when i move to production mode? i mean will a remote user be able to donwload the js files while not being on localhost?

**ANSWER:**
**@BalusC** made me realize where was the mistake in my choice. I didn't realize that this kind of JS fetching only works with a GET request. I thought it would work with a POST and thus disable the GET method on the servlet (so that the JS cannot be accessed directly from the url bar).

In addition , what **@David** said is true, however i was trying to make it not very straightforward to read the JS source.

So i found that **@Todd Chaffee** is absolutely right, lesson learned: 
**"1) Security through obscurity is a documented bad practice."**

Comment: This approach makes absolutely no sense. The enduser has just to open servlet's URL instead to get the JS file. E.g. http://localhost:8080/contextname/servlet/mainLoader.js I'm also not sure how "asynchronously" makes sense in this context. It's just the webbrowser who is downloading the JS, not the webserver.

Comment: @BalusC the web browser using an ajax function(with return type script) calls the servlet, which itself loads the js file from WEB-INF as a java InputStream and read its bytes,flush, and then return the result to the function. Of course the webserver is downloading the JS but its the servlet that is returning the stream. Why doesn't it make sense? exactly why i wanted to know if its bad practice.. i am basically trying to do like a very small example of how for example facebook downloads its JS using ajax.

Comment: No, it's not the webserver who's downloading the file. It's the webbrowser. It makes absolutely no difference when placing the JS file outside `/WEB-INF` and changing the URL to point to that.

Comment: @BalusC it's a typo, meant "of course the webbrowser".

Comment: Then you should understand that it absolutely doesn't make any difference to the client whether you're serving the file straight form the webserver or through a homegrown servlet. In both cases, the client will still retrieve exactly the same file.

Comment: @BalusC yep of course, wt i didn't realize is that this kind of JS fetching only works currently with a GET request. Since it doesn't work with POST(which i was intending to do) , so yeah the user can access the JS through the url bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the initial question:

> *- Is this considered a bad practice?*

It's not necessarily a bad practice. It plain don't make sense. Why taking over the work of the serveltcontainer's builtin default servlet?

> *- Currently i am developing my app locally (localhost) , will this js loading system cause problems when i move to production mode? i mean will a remote user be able to donwload the js files while not being on localhost?*

This indicates that you're thinking that Java code runs in webbrowser (the client side). This assumption is wrong. Java code runs on webserver (the server side). It'll work equally good as long as you don't change the relative URLs.

---

As per the comments:

> *what I didn't realize is that this kind of JS fetching only works currently with a GET request. Since it doesn't work with POST (which I was intending to do), so yeah the user can access the JS through the url bar.*

POST is absolutely not more "secure" than GET as to "man in middle" attacks. POST is just intended for non-idempotent requests while GET is intended for idempotent requests. The only way to prevent your HTTP requests against "man in middle" attacks is to use HTTPS instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't hide JavaScript code from the user. Even if you inject additional code via a script tag, the user will be able to get the code with the help of tools like firebug.

If you want to protect code you should take a look at "minifiers" and "code obfuscation". Still, this will not protect sensitive data like passwords, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to both questions:

1) Security through obscurity is a documented bad practice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

2) Remote users **must** be able to download any js file that the browser uses.  So they will definitely have access to your scripts.  I don't see a problem with the scripts living on a local file system, and moving from localhost to production, but why not just test it?

Comment: i am reading the link you gave me. Concerning part 2), by must u mean "have to" or "yes they will be able to download" in such an architecture?

Comment: If mainloader.js is running in the browser, which I suspect based on your example, then it will need to download the additional scripts.  If you are hard-coding 'localhost', then I'm pretty sure the browser is going to try to download the additional scripts from the remote user's location, which wouldn't work, unless they had the scripts locally stored.